# Es6 - Match two different object keys with different name

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am working on two API's that I don't have permission to change their field names (Sample below)

```
const api1 = {
  studentId: 'abc',
  studentName: 'John Doe',
  studentAge: 19,
  course: 'Engineering',
}


const api2 = {
  id,
  personalInfo: {
    name,
    age
  },
  course:
}
```

Basically I will need to transfer the data from api2 to api 1 so what I did is:

```
const payload = {}
payload["studentId"] = api2.id,
payload["studentName"] = api2.personalInfo.name,
payload["studentAge"] = api2.personalInfo.age,
payload["course"] = api2.course,
```

Is there a way how I can do this dynamically ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: I don't think so: that's because you need to know the nested substructure of `api2` before you can perform the mapping to a one-level deep object.

Comment: this looks like the most likely way to do what you do

Comment: so I guess will just settle for this one, kinda looks dirty specially if there would be more keys... anyways thank you so much guys!

Comment: should that be `payload["studentIdd"] = api2.id`

Comment: would `const {id:studentId, personalInfo: {name:studentName, age:studentAge}, course} = api2, payload = {studentId, studentName, studentAge, course};` do what you want?

Comment: @JaromandaX apologies yes, that should be ```payload["studentId"] = api2.id would edit.  Thanks for the suggestion but what I am looking for is similar with @nina answer below. My bad if I didn't make it clear enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could take a wrapper object which wraps all wanted properties of the given API to a new API.

This approach takes an object which maps the given properties to new format/names of the wanted structure by getting the entries of the object and iterating these until a non object is found and then it assigns the value to a new object. If an object is found it take this object and gets the values from the nested object.

If nested target properties are supplied, like

```
{ studentName: 'personalInfo.name' }
```

(for example for creating API2 from API1) you need to split the value and create an object with a nested structure, like

```
const
    path = value.split('.'),
    last = path.pop();

path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, target)[last] = source[key];
```

in the `else` part.

```js
const
    assign = (source, wrapper, target = {}) => {
        Object.entries(wrapper).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') assign(source[key], value, target);
            else target[value] = source[key];
        });
        return target;
    },
    api1 = { studentId: 'abc', studentName: 'John Doe', studentAge: 19, course: 'Engineering' },
    api2 = { id: 'someId', personalInfo: { name: 'someName', age: 'someAge' }, course: 'someCourse' },
    wrapper = { id: 'studentId', personalInfo: { name: 'studentName', age: 'studentAge' }, course: 'course' },
    payload = assign(api2, wrapper);

console.log(payload);
```

Comment: I feel like this suffers from over-engineering. It does the same thing as a series of assignments but is less readable and less flexible. It also doesn't answer the question (some way to do it dynamically).

Comment: @Ouroborus so it's much better to do it by just assignment ?

Comment: It isn't necessarily better, just easier to read and more flexible. If you happen to have a lot of different kinds of conversions to do, it might make sense to go so far as to make a function like this, perhaps in order to make configuration accessible without things like a re-compile if that happens to be a step. It's just a fact that you're not going to be able to do your task in a dynamic way because there's no way for a computer to clearly understand how the fields between the two APIs need to match up without you explicitly defining it and assignments are about as good as any other way.